# Flutter app crashes when I produce appbundle

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

From today, after updating the dependencies, when I build the app doing appbundle, crash (not making an apk)

I print the result with flutter build appbundle --verbose

Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.

```
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:780:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
#11     runCommandAndStreamOutput (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
#12     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#15     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#17     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#18     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#19     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using? Seems similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40445

Comment: I use the last version